# Pause HTML5 video if it was interacted with using spacebar like youtube?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using "vanilla" javascript :) I'm trying to replicate youtube's method of pausing video if spacebar is pressed. I'm able to get video to pause if the event is bound to the window but not the video, here is my code.

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
     if (evt.keyCode === 32) {
        if (video.paused) {
          video.play(); 
        }
        else { 
          video.pause(); 
        } 
    }
 });
```

As in the code above, using **window** works, but if i change **window** to **video** it doesn't work anymore even if I've interacted with the video player. Reason of necessity : if user is watching a video and wants to leave a comment, everytime they press the spacebar the video starts and pauses over and over again. So I need it to only pause or start if user has interacted with the video player and not clicked anywhere else, like youtube. Kind thanks.

Edit: Noticed youtube uses Tabindex (never used it before), to make controls focusable, so that has something to do with it? That's only controls though and not the actual screen.

Comment: can you set a flag if the focus is on the comments box that disables the play/pause toggle, but when the focus is elsewhere in the window it works as needed?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but with that scenario issue is that the user wouldn't be able to scroll down using spacebar, that would only benefit if user was entering some sort of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code what exactly you want.

```js
$(function(){
    var videoID=$('#videoID')[0];
$(videoID).hover(function() {
    this.focus();
}).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
       if(e.keyCode === 32){
           if(videoID.paused) {
               videoID.play(); 
           } else {
               videoID.pause(); 
           }
           return false;
       }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="400" controls id="videoID">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Set a Flag**

To extend off of the comments in your question, rather than setting a flag for indicating focus on the comments, you can set a flag for indicating a focus on the video.

```
var focused_vid; // Used to figure out whether the video is focused on.
```

You set this flag to be true when the video is clicked and the page is loaded, and set to false when an element on the page is clicked that isn't the video.I understand you are using "vanilla" JavaScript, so the following is a dirty version, that may or may not work for all browsers, but it displays the general idea:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var focused_vid;

    document.body.onclick = function(){
       // Get the top-most element that triggered this.
       var clicked_element = event.target;

       // If the video was clicked, we will set the flag to true.
       if(clicked_element.id != "video_id"){
         focused_vid = false;
       } else {
         focused_vid = true;
       }         
    }
</script>
```

Then modify your code a little bit:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
     if (evt.keyCode === 32 && focused_vid) {
        if (video.paused) {
          video.play(); 
        }
        else { 
          video.pause(); 
        } 
    }
 });
```

**Things to Note**

If the javascript loads before the body element, you will receive errors like "cannot receive ID of null", or cannot add element to null. If you get this, simply make sure that the JavaScript executes after the page loads with the [onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).